# Labeling and Data (ChartJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am working on a code with an API. I need to create a line chart for these things called tickets. I need to call the information for them from the API. It has the ticket ID, date, and description. For the labeling, I have four weeks of the month. If I don't call it for every week, the chart won't show up. However, when I do this, instead of the information on a chart popping up, an alert does with all of the information for each week.

```
   var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Tickets",
        fillColor: "rgba(100,200,244,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(100,200,244,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(200,255,255,.7)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [$.get("http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/", function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}).fail(function() {alert("FAIL");}), $.get("http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/", function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}).fail(function() {alert("FAIL");}), $.get("http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/", function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}).fail(function() {alert("FAIL");}), $.get("http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/", function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}).fail(function() {alert("FAIL");}) ] };
```

If you need the full code (this has CSS, HTML, and the JavaScript), [click here](https://gist.github.com/notpyrocumulus/ca73b954303039b5b460).

Answer (score 0):

$.get does not evaluate to a return value like a normal function call.

When the data is received from http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/, your callback function gets called. In your case that is

```
 function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}
```

You have access to the returned `data` **inside** this callback function. And you're just alerting it. Which is why you simply get an alert alone. You need to move your chart drawing code into this call back function. Something like

```
 window.onload = function () {
     $.get("http://velocity.data.wpengine.com:3000/tickets/list/", function(data){
        var lineChartData = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(100,200,244,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(100,200,244,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(200,255,255,.7)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: data,
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(100,200,244,0)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(100,200,244,0)",
                pointColor: "rgba(200,255,255,0)",
                pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
                pointHighlightFill: "#rgba(255,255,255,0)",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            }]
        };

        var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx1).Line(lineChartData, {
            showScale: false,
            pointDot: true,
            responsive: true

        });

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });

        ....
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to mention that your CSS is actually LESS or SASS (I see nested rulesets in there) and you also have a style block and a head end tag before </body> which you might want to clean up.